# querying based on the additional pivot table column in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pivot-table, eloquent

I have a User Model with the columns id, name, email and

a Course Model with the columns id, name, code and

a pivot table course_user.

Course and User has many-to-many relation

course_user table contains columns course_id, user_id, section

While taking courses, some users will be listed as 'Pending' in pivots section column and some users will be listed as 'A', 'B' etc in section column.

**Question:** I want to get those courses which are taken by at least one user and section is 'Pending'
So far, I've tried these: 
In Course Model :

```
public function users(){

    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)
                ->withPivot('section');
                ->wherePivot('section', 'Pending');
}
```

Another Approach I've tried in course Model:

```
public function pendingUsers(){

    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)
                ->withPivot('section')
                ->wherePivot('section', 'like', 'Pending');
}
```

But all of these are giving me all of the courses.
Now, How can this job be done?

Comment: show us your controller code

Comment: I've used the method wherePivot('section', 'Pending')  while querying in the controller & it says that:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pivot' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from courses where exists (select * from users inner join course_user on users.id = course_user.user_id where courses.id = course_user.course_id and pivot = section))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Define the relationship:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withPivot('section');
}
```

Then:

```
Course::whereHas('users', function($q) {
    $q->where('course_user.section', 'Pending');
})
->get();
```

Comment: 1st method gives the following error
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pivot' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `courses` where exists (select * from `users` inner join `course_user` on `users`.`id` = `course_user`.`user_id` where `courses`.`id` = `course_user`.`course_id` and `pivot` = section))

Comment: @MisbahAhmad yeah, looks like it works only with the `with()`. So, use the second one then.

Comment: If I use the following code, it gives right outputs. But would it be a problem for other queries when I need all courses taken by a specific user?
    

    public function users(){


        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)
                    ->withPivot('section')
                    ->wherePivot('section', 'like', '%Pending%');
    
}

Comment: @MisbahAhmad just add this `where()` to any query where you need to filter by status.